# Playing a locally saved video in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, html5-video, local-files

I'm building a small Angular application, in which the user should be able to view a collection of locally saved videos and save the collection in order to rewatch these videos at a later point in time. The paths of the videos are saved in a JSON-File, which means I only have access to the string of a path like this:

> C:\My Videos\UploadedVideo.mp4

Passing this path to the src of a video-HTML-element doesn't allow me to play it though. I've seen workarounds where a input-element is used and the file is passed to the video-element, but this doesn't work in my case as I have the file path and don't want the user to reselect the videos over and over again.

Comment: What happens if you try `src` path as: `file:///C:/My%20Videos/UploadedVideo.mp4`?

Answer (score 2):

You're not able to use your system path in browser.

You have two options:

- Add your videos to your `Assets` folder in Angular
- Put video online 
  (*eg:* create Bucket on Amazon S3 for this kind of files and access it via the bucket link).